# Split Json array into table rows using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory and I have Json files in azure Datalake. Each Json file contain an array of Jsons. I want to copy each Jsons of the array into Azure SQL row. I tried to do it with copy activity, but it automatically flatten the Json and I want to keep it original. I cannot use DataFlow.
The following pic describe what I want to achieve (don't mention the values of the table)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used Lookup activity with Json linked service. then, with script activity, I wrote each @item() to the azure sql table row
[image]

Comment: be aware from  a finops point of view. doing all from one activity is far more better then doing it from multiple activities.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to copy each Json array into a single column of a row, you can
  use `openjson` in script activity. Below is the approach.
- Lookup activity is taken, and Json file is taken as the dataset in the activity.

[image]

- Then the output of the lookup activity is stored in the variable `Json`
  of string type. The value is assigned using **set variable** activity.
  Value for variable Json: `@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value)`
  [image]
- Script activity is taken and linked service for Azure SQL database is given. Script is given as

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(4000)=N'@{variables('Json')}';
INSERT INTO test_tgt
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (
col1 nvarchar(max) '$' AS JSON
);
```

This script will insert the data into the table **test_tgt** which is already created.

[image]

**SQL table output**

[image]

Comment: THNX, In this way I save the foreach activity

Comment: id 5, should be rajaraja. vallavaraiyan doesn't belong in this dataset, but can probably be appended to the final index if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use dynamic expressions here.
Try to parse the output of your select activity ( the one that fetch the json file from your datalake).

Here is an exemple that would extract two seperate json variables from an array of json on a datalake.

[image: my pipeline]

the json file is like :

[image: my json file]

lookup activity would be as below :

[image: lookup activity]

variables are :

[image: variabes]

output of the lookup activity is :

[image: output of lookup activity]

To parse the array of json (output of the lookup activity) we use the following :

```
@array(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0])

NOTE : [number] would give the item number of the array
[0] : first item
[1] scond item
..
```

[image: setvariable]

Results :

variable 1 gets :

```
@array(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0])
```

[image: var 1]

variable 2 gets:

```
@array(activity('Lookup1').output.value[1])
```

[image: var 2]

Hope this would help.